# Ubuntu WhatsApp desktop app with call features

Tags: software-recommendation

I like to know is there any WhatsApp application for desktop or browser extension with video call ability in Ubuntu, i have tried this app and web base of WhatsApp that don't have call futures:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading whatsdesk from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: yes, But  i think those are web based and the problem it form that!

Comment: I don't use WhatsApp, but I have a feeling that this is something only WhatsApp can fix. They have support the platform first.

Comment: There's another option that I don't see mentioned here, but I don't have time to write in detail (maybe someone else can do it?): run a virtual Android machine and install Whatsapp for Android there.

Answer (score 2):

The calls features are only available in WhatsApp native Desktop app 64-bit(Which the official website show that only Mac and window native app for desktop are available ), not in WhatsApp Web,and unfortunately they haven't developed the native app for Linux. The one which we are installing and using from Ubuntu-Software is Web version. That's why the call feature is not available in that.

> As you can see in the screenshot it is written that this is Web
> version

[image]

> Same is written in the when we go to web.whatsapp.com.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

WhatsApp desktop version does not support audio and video calls. As a good alternative you can use Skype. [Here is how to install Skype in Ubuntu.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html.en)

If you are really interested in using WhatsApp, then the solution is to install an Android emulator such as [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and within that emulator install and use WhatsApp. This will enable the video and audio calling features.

Comment: Notice that if you install WhatsApp on an emulator, you will be logged out from your phone.

Answer (score -2):

Use **Signal** or **Telegram** instead of WhatsApp.
https://signal.org/de/download/
https://desktop.telegram.org/

Many people are using it parallel or now as main-App for mobile communication.

**Signal** is made with the help of the original WhatsApp-Developer and it is much better. You have better voice quality if you call someone, you have Video-call integrated in the desktop-App and everything what you have with the phone-App. You can send pictures with original quality, they will not be converted down if you do not want it.

The disadvantages are:

- If you switch your phone, the old messages will not be copied to the new phone. It have something to do with security. I do not know how this backup-function works. You can make a backup of your message-data, but don't know how to put it in my new phone.

**Telegram** works very well too, there are more options as in Signal and it is a bit more easy to handle.

Comment: You can also add information about [Telegram](https://askubuntu.com/q/1378912/124466). And here is the information for [ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379276/updating-telegram-desktop-on-arm64-ubuntu-21-04)

Comment: I have tested it now for a while and it is very useful and easy to use.

Comment: It's like an answer copied from ChatGPT

Comment: @RikudoPain - No, I wrote this and I am using all these apps. Why do you think this?

Comment: since it looks like it doesn't connect with the question.

Comment: @RikudoPain - First: Read the question. Second: Find a good answer what is helpful for the user. So I gave him the best possible solution for his problem. With WhatsApp it does not work and this will possibly never change. With Signal and Telegram he can make a video- or voice call to other people. Possibly they have to go to Signal to talk with him, but it is not difficult to use a second app. This are his only options. If I would answer the question in a stupid way, I could say "no, doesn't work". But this is not helpful. Now he has a way to go.

Comment: @MikroPower Yes, read the question, he did not ask for alternatives, if it's not possible then it's not, you never mention it's not possible instead ask to use other apps. Some people are tied to using some tech and can't just replace it with other tech as they like. And yes, answering with "no, doesn't work" looks like a stupid answer, but it's more helpful than giving another alternative (check how much people mark your answer as helpful compared to someone that truthfully answers that it can't be done)

Comment: @Rikudo Pain - In my culture it is rude to leave people without any option what they could do instead. To write "doesn't work" is simple, but the next step is mostly to find a alternative way. If you wait till he ask for a alternative option, then you can sometimes wait 4 ever, because some people do not come up with the idea to ask and then they give up. Sometimes people need a little push in the right direction to be successful. I had sometimes the situation that everyone was against me, but at the end I was right and not the majority. People are often simply dumb and to not learn.