# Updating Telegram desktop on arm64 ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, telegram, arm64

How to update telegram desktop on Ubuntu 21.04 in an arm64 computer?

Every time, a notification pops up, and asks to update it.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu Q&A support site; if you have a bug report (including request to update a package), it belongs on a bug report that is read by developers; not users who use this site.  Please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs & read the site rules - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1378912/124466) is a related question for regular amd64 computers.

Answer (score 3):

The apt version of telegram-desktop is not updated during the lifecycle of an Ubuntu release, due to reasons described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/124466).

---

The snap package for telegram-desktop has arm64 builds, and it hosts the latest version. Uninstall the old version of telegram (`sudo apt remove telegram-desktop`, assuming you installed with apt), and enter the following commands in a terminal.

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

---

The flatpak version also hosts arm64 builds.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.telegram.desktop
```